# OrientDB multi-node configuration: hazelcast issues

Tags: orientdb, hazelcast

I have OrienDB 2.1.4 cluster of 3 nodes with basic configuration. The only change in hazelcast.xml I made is to replace multicast by implicit tcp-ip hosts list.

After heavy request to DB (select without joins, about 300k rows in result set), OrientDB stops response to network connection attempts from application (OrientDB Studio is still working), the follwoing exceptions continuously appear in logs:

on master node

```
2016-02-24 10:02:17:647 INFO  [10.10.10.124]:2434 [zertodb] [3.3.5] Remaining migration tasks in queue => 1 [InternalPartitionService][10.10.10.124]:2434 [zertodb] [3.3.5] Received data format is invalid. (An old version of Hazelcast may be running here.)
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Length check failed, maybe broken bytestream or wrong stream position
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:354)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:341)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:454)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.MulticastService.receive(MulticastService.java:155)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.MulticastService.run(MulticastService.java:113)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Length check failed, maybe broken bytestream or wrong stream position
        at com.hazelcast.nio.UTFEncoderDecoder.readUTF0(UTFEncoderDecoder.java:505)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.UTFEncoderDecoder.readUTF(UTFEncoderDecoder.java:77)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readUTF(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:450)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.ConfigCheck.readData(ConfigCheck.java:219)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.JoinMessage.readData(JoinMessage.java:80)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.JoinRequest.readData(JoinRequest.java:64)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:111)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:39)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:335)
        ... 4 more
```

on other nodes:

```
[10.10.10.194]:2434 [zertodb] [3.3.5] Received data format is invalid. (An old version of Hazelcast may be running here.)
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:354)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:341)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:454)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.ConfigCheck.readData(ConfigCheck.java:215)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.JoinMessage.readData(JoinMessage.java:80)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.JoinRequest.readData(JoinRequest.java:64)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:111)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:39)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:335)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:454)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.MulticastService.receive(MulticastService.java:155)
        at com.hazelcast.cluster.MulticastService.run(MulticastService.java:113)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1379)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:196)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.readObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:335)
        ... 12 more
```

The same query with smaller result set works fine.

Comment: Have you already tried to upgrade to last hotfix? OrientDb v2.1.11? We upgraded also Hazelcast to use v3.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this issue  https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/4327 about your problem with hazelcast.

Hope it helps.